# What is wrong with my read/write code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a average and to save the last number added to average aswell but my code always "return" me this in logcat:

```
07-06 08:14:44.646    9981-9981/com.example.emilio.notification E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.emilio.notification, PID: 9981
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.stackmyArray(MainActivity.java:207)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.writeMyArray(MainActivity.java:192)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:47)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:109)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my code : (write/read file is the code for the last number and the write/read the array is for the average. I started trying to do a array but i couldn't append, so if your question have a array instead of my "logic", its ok. The stack code is the increment, so if I add one more number to the average, it will do the right division)

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("estrela.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}



private String readFromFile() {

    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("estrela.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
private void writeMyArray(double rate){
    //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("arraymedia.txt", true)));
    //.println(rate);
    Double ratex2 = rate + Double.parseDouble(readMyArray());

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("test3.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        if(readMyArray() == "")
        {
            outputStreamWriter.write(0);
        }
        outputStreamWriter.write(Double.toString(ratex2));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
        stackmyArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }


}
private void stackmyArray()
{
    if(readMyArray() != "") {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("test3count.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            if(stackread() == "")
            {outputStreamWriter.write(0);}
            Double stack = Double.parseDouble(stackread()) + 1;
            outputStreamWriter.write(Double.toString(stack));
            outputStreamWriter.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    else
    {

        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("test3count.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(Integer.toString(1));
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
private String readMyArray(){
    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("test3.txt");


        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}

private String stackread(){
    String ret = "";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("test3count.txt");

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

With the Keppil answer, I have this logcat now:

```
07-06 08:38:25.223  18958-18958/com.example.emilio.notification E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.emilio.notification, PID: 18958
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "��"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.example.emilio.notification.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:114)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: which line is 207?. By the way `readMyArray() == ""` that does not compare strings, use `equals`. and don´t go on reading and reading and reading a file, cache the read value.

Comment: I'm a beginner as you can see. How can I cache the read value and save it in case the app is closed?

Comment: `String whatever = whateverToHave()`

Comment: wheré´s the call to `writeToFile()`. What value are you writing there? I suppose it is an empty string and that´s why the read fails with `""`

Comment: WriteToFile is not the problem, because i'm just writing. The error is in WritetoArray, because I need to get the file "value" to add it the new values

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: The second error isn't even from the code you are showing us here, but you probably have a similar problem as the first one that was solved. See if you can apply a similar solution there.

Comment: stringBuilder.append(receiveString); your always write an empty string to the string builder, why so!. Read the stream from the inputstream and append it to the stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the `String` is `""` before converting, but then you still try to convert it:

```
if(stackread() == "")
{outputStreamWriter.write(0);}
Double stack = Double.parseDouble(stackread()) + 1;
outputStreamWriter.write(Double.toString(stack));
```

Also, calling `stackread()` twice might be problematic, and you are using `==` to compare strings. Change this to:

```
String stackRead = stackread();
if (stackRead.equals("")) {
    outputStreamWriter.write(0);
} else {
    Double stack = Double.parseDouble(stackRead) + 1;
    outputStreamWriter.write(Double.toString(stack));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the `==` issue? I have commented on that too.

Comment: eduyayo, the file is empty, that's why I need to compare with "".

Comment: This solved OPs first problem, so I don't understand why you would downvote. The next problem (`parseInt`) isn't even in the provided code.

Comment: Why downvoting? I thought that you didn't understand the logic and I felt that I needed to explain to you, because you are trying to help. Thanks anyway.  I'll check the rest of the code now @Keppil.